# Define buttonnummer programmatically?

Tags: xcode, string, swift, random, numbers

I'm trying to set the title of a button in Swift. The button title and number is random. I have button1..16. Swift doesn't accept 'button' with 
'String doesn't have a member named 'setTitle'. 
How can I make Swift accept this?

```
var buttonNumber = arc4random_uniform(16) + 1
var targetNumber = arc4random_uniform(20) + 1
var button = "button\(buttonNumber)"
button.setTitle("\(targetNumber)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep your buttons in an array then it is much easier to access them by an index value.

If you are manually setting up your view then you can do something like this in your `viewDidLoad()`:

```
self.buttons =  [UIButton]()
... add buttons to your view and to the buttons array ...
```

If you are using Interface Builder to create your view then you can connect all the buttons more easily using an *Outlet Collection*:

```
@IBOutlet strong var buttons: NSArray!
```

Then to change a button with a specific (or random) index, you can do this:

```
var buttonNumber = arc4random_uniform(16)
var targetNumber = arc4random_uniform(20) + 1
self.buttons[buttonNumber].setTitle("\(targetNumber)",
    forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Note that the `buttonNumber` is a zero-based array index so you don't want to add `1` to it.